# How can I negate a condition in Apache RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to serve .xhtml files as

- `application/xhtml+xml` if the browser says that it accepts it.
- `text/html` otherwise

Then, I have this code:

```
AddType text/html .xhtml
<Files "*.xhtml">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept}" "application/xhtml\+xml\s*(?:,|$)"
    RewriteRule .* - [T=application/xhtml\+xml]
</Files>
```

And it works.
But I think it could be simplified negating the condition. Something like

```
<Files "*.xhtml">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept}" !"application/xhtml\+xml\s*(?:,|$)"
    RewriteRule .* - [T=text/html]
</Files>
```

but it doesn't work: I always get a `text/html` page, even if XHTML is supported.

Comment: The `!` should work to negate it just as you have it. Is that not the result you are getting?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski No, I get a `text/html` page even if XHTML is supported

Comment: Maybe you're already getting text/html from e.g. mime.types, so skipping the T=text/html is not useful.

Comment: @covener No, the default MIME type for .xhtml is `application/xhtml+xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the 2nd option should be something like this:

```
<Files "*.xhtml">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept} !application/xhtml\+xml 
    RewriteRule .* - [T=text/html]
</Files>
```

That way, if the `HTTP:Accept` variable does not contain the string  `application/xhtml+xml` the MIME type is set to `text/html`.

### Answer to OP comment:

**Regex in the question:** `application/xhtml\+xml\s*(?:,|$)`

- `application/xhtml` = Match the characters **application/xhtml** literally.
- `\+`  = Match the character **+** literally.
- `xml` = Match the characters **xml** literally.
- `\s*` = Match a *whitespace character* (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.) after `application/xhtml+xml`, between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).
- `?:`  = The question mark (**?**) and the colon (**:**) denote this group (Inside the round brackets) is not a back reference.
- `,|$` = Match the character `,` literally **OR** assert position at the end of the string.

**Regex in this answer:**

Includes only the relevant string segment: **application/xhtml+xml** to ensure there is a match and therefore the rule is NOT applied when this string is present.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But what does `\s*(?:,|$)` exactly do? And why must I remove it if I want to negate the condition?

Comment: But I don't understand why `%{HTTP:Accept}` always matches `!"application/xhtml\+xml\s*(?:,|$)"`. For example, if the browser sends `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`, then `%{HTTP:Accept}` matches `"application/xhtml\+xml\s*(?:,|$)"`, but I think it shouldn't match `!"application/xhtml\+xml\s*(?:,|$)"`.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you don't understand, but let's see: You say `but I think it shouldn't match !"application/xhtml\+xml\s*(?:,|$)"` And it doesn't, satisfying the condition requirement (NOT) and that's why the rule was always applied, even when `application/xhtml+xml` was present, which was the problem as far as I understand. Reducing the regex string to the relevant segment: `application/xhtml+xml` ensures the rule is NOT applied when that string is present.

Comment: Maybe I can explain my doubts better with JavaScript examples: http://jsfiddle.net/BMT63/

Comment: @Oriol It's the same. The NOT condition is met when the regular expression does not match the pattern of the incoming string, because it's different (This case) or just because the string is not present.  Your condition `RewriteCond "%{HTTP:Accept}" !"application/xhtml\+xml\s*(?:,|$)"` is saying: If this regular expression `application/xhtml\+xml\s*(?:,|$)` does NOT match the Accept variable, apply the rule.  Well, that regular expression never matches the Accept variable, even when the string `application/xhtml+xml` is indeed present, so the rule is always applied.

Comment: @Oriol On the other hand, this regular expression `application/xhtml+xml` does match the Accept variable and therefore the rule is NOT applied. I understand you have already confirmed my answer works, but if you think it doesn't solve your problem, it's okay. I certainly understand you want to know what it does, but I have done my best trying to explain it. Maybe my wording is not clear enough.

Comment: You say "`application/xhtml\+xml\s*(?:,|$)` (...) never matches the Accept variable, even when the string `application/xhtml+xml` is indeed present". Why? If it never matches, then the first code I wanted to simplify shouldn't have worked.

Comment: The rule is applied if **the condition is met** by **NOT** matching the Accept variable. You say, quote:  "but it doesn't work:  **I always get a text/html page, even if XHTML is supported**" So, what is it you don't understand now?  I don't know the incoming Accept variable exact content, that's also missing in your question, so I only know your rule fails because you say so (In the quoted sentence above) and can only guess why it fails.  What I do know is why the rule in my answer works and I have explained it several times.

Comment: Maybe I'm too stubborn, given that your answer works and I understand it. But I want to understand what's happening. In my previous comment I was talking about the code I wanted to simplify, which worked, not about my attempt, which didn't. And I understand that *the rule is applied if the condition is met by NOT matching the Accept variable*, but I think that the header `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8` should match `application/xhtml\+xml\s*(?:,|$)`, so the rule shouldn't be applied.

Comment: Now I understand your concern but as I said: It does NOT match. What else do you want me to answer? If you test it in `RegexBuddy`, for example, the only characters that match are the literal ones. These: **application/xhtml+xml,**, using both, the normal Accept string and the regex in your previous comment. So your assumption is not right, it does NOT match and the rule is always applied. If you don't have `RegexBuddy` or a similar program, you can test the regex [here](http://regexpal.com/). But the best test is: **the rule is always applied with the regex in your question**.

Comment: But I don't see the difference between http://imageshack.us/a/img266/6363/regexp2.gif and http://imageshack.us/a/img845/223/regexp1.gif .I think both should work, or neither.